# Time Difference with same column MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `adminmsg` which holds `errorid`,`errorcode`, `errordesc`, `errortime` and `errordate`. for every error happens i'm saving it. What i need is how can i get total time error 2 ocurred in a day? 
Thanks

Comment: Note that some would consider storing time and date as a single entity.

Comment: op needs to make more clear whats the question. give an expected result as an example could help

Answer (score 1):

I took today as am example for a specific day

```
select count(*)
from adminmsg
where errordate = curdate()
and errorcode = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understood your question but try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`errordate`,' ',`errortime`) AS errordatetime FROM adminmsg WHERE errorid = 2
```

this will return the date and the time of error with errorid = 2 in one value

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using aggregation:

```
select errordate, sum(errorcode = 2) 
from adminmsg
group by errordate
order by errordate;
```

This gives the values for all days in the data.  You can, of course, add a `where` clause to get any specific day(s) that you want.